# Imputing values for missing values into an existing panda dataframe from a series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series which values that I want to plug into my panda dataframe column. How should I write my code in such a way that my values nicely fill in the NaN, which is taken from the series in order?

```
     col1  
0     NaN   
1     6    
2     NaN    
3     4    
4     3    
5     NaN

Series 
0       9
1       7
2       10

End result:

   col1  
0     9  
1     6    
2     7   
3     4    
4     3     
5     10
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A quick tip: Without post a code, you don't get answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loc` access:

```
df.loc[df.col1.isna(), 'col1'] = s.values
```

Output:

```
   col1
0   9.0
1   6.0
2   7.0
3   4.0
4   3.0
5  10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter `NaN` values and assign those from the other series as a list

```
serie2 = pd.Series([9, 7, 10])
df.loc[df.col1.isna(), 'col1'] = serie2.to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Noticed you need to pass a column header to specify where to fill**

Instead, do

```
series = {0: pd.Series([9, 7, 10])
df = df.fillna(series)
```

---

You can pass a series to the pd.fillna() method.

[image]

Comment: Did you notice you fill everything with `9`?